# How to enable mute and volume buttons on HP Elitebook 8460p?

Tags: sound, hp

I have a HP Elitebook 8460p, which works mostly perfectly with Ubuntu, except for a few quirks. One of them is that the mute and volume buttons do not work.

The volume buttons are mapped to <kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> and <kbd>F7</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

Since I do not own that laptop, I am unable to confirm this for myself, but it is worth attempting to fix the issue.

Note: To return to your desktop after trying this, you will have to press **Alt+F7** or **Ctrl+Alt+F7**
Also worth noting - your desktop may be located on F8 instead of F7.

Press **Ctrl+Alt+F1** and then type these commands, and press the key combos that aren't working for you after issuing each of these commands -

```
showkey --scancodes
showkey --keycodes
```

Go back to your desktop check if your volume keys are working.

Comment: Well here's the deal with that, I can't see anything on my ttys right now lol.

Comment: You can try running it in a normal terminal. Its just that running it in a normal terminal does not always work, so I laid out the steps for running it in a tts. If the program shows up in a normal terminal and shows you your key presses, then it pretty much worked, even if it says that it may not work. When it really does fail, it does not show you your key presses.

Comment: I got the ttys back up now. All of them give codes. None of them work after switching back to the desktop, however. I think they need to be remapped.
 
Do you know how to rempap the keys? I don't remember. If you can give a straight forward method, and it works, I'll accept this as the answer.

Comment: Note: I was able to run these commands in a Gnome terminal on Ubuntu 18.04, but I had to prefix them with `sudo`, otherwise I got a `Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console` error

Answer (score -1):

There's an fn button between the Ctrl button on the bottom left of the keyboard and a windows button on the right. Hold down into the fn button and press f6 or f7 and it'll work

Comment: Specifically, the volume buttons do not emit scan codes: neither the destinated side-buttons, not the F6/F7 keys; that's why the question.